# problem with svg in html tributes and google charts timeline - can't change chart width

Tags: javascript, html, svg, charts, google-visualization

I have the same kind of chart used in other locations in my project, and I did not changed anything.

The problem i'm getting is that no matter what i do the horizontal size does not changes...

obs- Both charts presented are in the same page but use unique identifiers and are in distinct divs.

obs- I already tried to remove the chart that is working but nothing changed.

i'm getting this layout:

[[image: error layout]

When i should be getting this (already tried with the same exact code)

[image]

Using the inspector I'm getting this info:

[image]

The code i'm using is:

```
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
          ['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['Torre 1 - 145', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['Torre 2 - 1A', new Date(2019, 0, 26), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],]);

chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

with this div to present it:

```
<div id="example3.1" style="height: 200px;">
```

UPDATE:

Following the suggestion of WhiteHat I updated my code!
It looks like WhiteHat is right! the problem is in the tabs and I tried updating my code to this (once again WhiteHat suggestion), and it still doesn't work!

I tried to change the default tab when loading the page and the chart loaded great...
Updated code(not working):

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {

  // listen for tab shown event
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // determine which tab is visible based on tab text
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    switch ($(e.target).html()) {
      case 'Vista por Contrato':
        drawChart1();
        break;



   case 'Vista por Fracções':
        drawChart2();
        break;
    }
  });

  function drawChart1() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        ['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['Torre 1 - 145', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['Torre 2 - 1A', new Date(2019, 0, 26), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],?>
    ]);
    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }

  function drawChart2() {
    // code for chart 2
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Contrato');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Season Start Date');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Season End Date');

      data.addRows([
          ['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['Teste', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['Teste', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['WBOX LDA', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],]);

var options = {
  height: 450,
  timeline: {
    groupByRowLabel: false
  }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  // draw chart on initial tab
  drawChart2();

});
```

This is the code I have for my tabs (since it looks the problem starts here!).

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
<li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fraccoes">Vista por Fracções</a></li>
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contratos">Vista por Contrato</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#notificacoes">Notificações</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is the code for my bootstrap tabs:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');

    });
});
```

Comment: What other styling rules are being applied? How wide is the `container`?

Comment: Ok, in the inspector, can you verify that the container is larger than 400px? Try to add this CSS rule: `#example3a > svg { width: 100% }` and rename the ID to `example3a` - some rules may not be applied correctly because `.` denotes a class selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

in the code suggested by @whitehat there was an issue. I don't know if the problem was mine, or in suggestion, but i manage to solve it. The resize function wasn't working because it wasn't calling the correct charts. The names where not standard and because of that it was not working.

where is the corrected code:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {

  // bootstrap tabs
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');

  });

  // listen for tab shown event
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // determine which tab is visible based on tab text
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    drawChart1();
    drawChart2();

  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    switch ($(e.target).html()) {
      case 'Vista por Fracções':
        drawChart1();
        break;

      case 'Vista por Contrato':
        drawChart2();
        break;
    }
  }

  // code for chart 1
  var chart1 = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('example3'));
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data1.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'fracao' });
  data1.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'contrato' });
  data1.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  data1.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  data1.addRows([
     ['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['AA AGUIAR - 1', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['Torre 1 - 145', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],['Torre 2 - 1A', new Date(2019, 0, 26), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],
  ]);
  var options1 = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 40,
      width: '100%'
    },
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true,
      singleColor: 'green' ,
     showRowLabels: true },
     width: '100%',
     height: '400',

  };
  // code for chart 2
  var chart2 = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn('string', 'NCONT');
  data2.addColumn('string', 'Contrato');
  data2.addColumn('date', 'Season Start Date');
  data2.addColumn('date', 'Season End Date');
  data2.addRows([
    ['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['Teste', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['drwerwer', new Date(2018, 9, 25), new Date(2019, 11, 31)],['Teste', new Date(2009, 0, 01), new Date(2016, 7, 18)],['WBOX LDA', new Date(2019, 0, 01), new Date(2025, 0, 01)],]);
  ]);

  var options2 = {
    height: 300,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: false,
      singleColor: 'orange' ,
     showRowLabels: false }

  };



  function drawChart1() {
    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
  }

  function drawChart2() {
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
  }

  // draw chart on initial tab

  drawChart2();
```

Now is working the bootstrap tabs!